# Erlang: How to prevent the werl window from closing upon termination?

Tags: erlang

If the erlang virtual machine terminates for any reason, the whole werl window get closed without a chance for the developer to see what went wrong. Any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

This might be the next-best thing to stopping the window from closing. After the window opens, but before the vm crashes, start a shell log file via the File |Open Logfile were menu. Then after it crashes, you will be able to open that file and see everything that was out putted to the shell.

Otherwise, if you are starting a release and the vm is crashing during the starting the release, I would advise starting a node with the same config.sys file but with no -boot file. Then you can start the elements of your release one at a time and see what is happening with a smaller chance killing the entire vm. If you are starting a node with a release (-boot bootfile) then if any of the applications of that release fail, the entire node shuts down.

Comment: Nice idea, but it closes very quickly. I have no time to do File |Open Logfile

Comment: How are starting the window, please tell us how you are starting werl, we need to know this.

Comment: Does it crash if you start werl and then fire up your module? If not, start werl, start the logging as described above and then start your module. Also, you know that all args are passed as strings, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think this is impossible. All processes including the werl window live inside the vm when it crashes everything crashes as well. The way to inspect errors when the erlang VM crashes is to look into the erl_crash.dump file.

Answer (score 0):

How do you start werl?
Try to start just cmd.exe before, and then in this command shell start werl. Then, when werl will crash, the command shell window will still be opened and you will be able to see werl's messages.

Comment: and this? - CMD.EXE /K "werl.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Something that happens very frequently is that when a window crashes, the werl process is still running in background.

Then if you try to start an new process with the same node name, the werl window opens and closes very quickly without any chance to get information. In this case I kill the werl process using the task manager, and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ERL.exe (not werl.exe) from the command line/cmd? The VM will crash but it will fall back to the command line (with the last error still displayed). Note, also as mentioned above using erl_crash.dump is your best option fr detailed analysis.

Comment: Because erl.exe is not stable enough under windows

Comment: I assumed you were running on the server. From what I understand Werl is just a nice wrapper (better UI support, copy/paste, font, scrollbar, etc) for windows (interactive development). When running service on the server I would still recommend ERL (with erlsrv).

Comment: No way! erl is different, less stable implementation than werl